# Topographic correction (for landuse analysis) with ArcMap 10 or QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I've been searching a tutorial to do topographic correction using ArcMap 10.2 or QGIS for days, unfortunately I can't find a good one that can explain the work (like which toolbox should I use).
so maybe some of you have some link to do the topographic tutorials.

Comment: Well, I already left the rasters with the same number of columns and rows and with the same coordinate system.
Even so, I still have not been able to do the topographical correction. Now the following error appears: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'csr' See log for more details. But, this appears in the LOG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS atleast, there is a tool called [Topographic correction](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/terrain_analysis_lighting/topographiccorrection.html) which you can access via *Processing toolbox* > *SAGA*:

[image: Processing toolbox]

[image: Topographic correction]

The following [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65026/several-algorithms-done-for-topographic-correction-black-spots-how-to-solve) might also be of some use.

There are a number of topographic tools available, if the above is not suitable then it would be best if you can provide additional information as to the kind of analysis you are looking for, what problems you have at the moment etc.

---

**Edit**:

Also, typing "Topographic" in the *Processing Toolbox* will give you a number of tools available:

[image: Topography in processing toolbox]

Comment: thank you so much sir @Joseph .
i'll try to do your advice on my project.

i'm doing landuse analysis using landsat7 in some surging/wavy terrain area, so much hills and in the image appear that the west slope darker than the east slope, so when i using the maximum likelihood classification, those areas wrongly interpreted.

Comment: i have some trouble when running that saga tollbox, there is an error "Input layers do not have the same grid extent" 
i try to clipping both DEM raster and landsat raster but that didn't solve the problem. do you sir know how to solve that.?
thanks in advance 
@joseph

Comment: Most welcome @IlyasNursyamsi . It would be best to ask that as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). I have not experienced this issue before although I have only worked with rasters a few times. Try using **Save as...** on the layers, set their CRS (**don't** use the _Set Layer CRS_ with right-click) and the projection CRS to the same, then see if the function works. Otherwise, ask it as a new question and hopefully others with more experience can help you.

Comment: You have to have the exact numbers of columns and rows between your image and DEM for the tool to work.

Answer (score 0):

For Qgis, it is interesting that the folders do not have accentuation, space and very long path.
Changing that, solved my problem.